# tSQL 2012 - table locking within TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following TRANSACTION structure:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN tran sometransaction  
   INSERT INTO local_table_1 (columns...) 
      SELECT (columns...) 
      FROM remote_table 
      WHERE (conditions, predicates)

   UPDATE local_table_1 
   SET column_A = value 
   WHERE....

   UPDATE local_table_1 
   SET column_B = value 
   WHERE....

   UPDATE local_table_1 
   SET column_C = value 
   WHERE....

   COMMIT tran sometransaction
END TRY
BEGIN catch
   ROLLBACK tran sometransaction    
END catch
```

I want to make sure that no one is allowed to read contents of `local_table_1` unless all statements within this **transaction** are over and have been committed.

Is there a way to set `WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)` on the whole transaction? I understand that tables lock automatically during the transaction execution however I could not find any explanation if that extends on external concurrent read processes.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to lock the entire table? SQL server had built in lock escalation to help avoid locking the entire table a single row update.

Comment: well... that's the thing, I know I have no other processes running against this table except the external reads which I am trying to prevent for the duration of the whole transaction. (the transaction goes like this: copy 10,000 records into the local table, update all 10,000 records 3x - 3 different update statements.) If anyone tries to read the table in between those update statements he/she will get un-updated data.

Comment: My question is why is it important that these other processes are not allowed to read the table? Unless you use NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED these processes won't see your changes until they are committed.

Comment: because if the external read is allowed during the unfinished transaction, the read may return a record-set with non-updated data (because the UPDATE statements did not finish their job yet).

Comment: No it will not read uncommitted transactions unless your external process is using a NOLOCK hint or READ UNCOMMITTED isolation.

Comment: @Sean - thank you, could you make this an official answer please? This is exactly what I needed to know yet did not find any documentation which would explicitly state that. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external process will not read uncommitted transactions unless your external process is using a NOLOCK hint or READ UNCOMMITTED isolation. This is all related to Isolation in reference to the ACID properties of sql. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Answer (score 0):

Set the transaction isolation level to READ COMMITTED or REPEATABLE READ before you begin your transaction. The following link has a description and example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: ..thanks, I read this MS post before I posted to SO but it states the following: "Specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but not committed by other transactions." It seems to me that it sets the isolation level of the transaction (what  transaction can access) from other sources and not isolating the transaction itself.